# problema con httpsession

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

tengo un problema con http session, creo la sesion en un servlet, pero cuando trato de recuperarla despues en el segundo, cuendo pongo cl.getNombre(); , me aparece como null, soy nuevo usando esto ( es mi primer codigo) si alguien me podria ayudar, muchas gracias. ya probe usando request.getsession (true)

```
HttpSession misession= request.getSession(); 
        int sl=c.getSaldo();
        String nom = cl.getNombre();
        String ap = cl.getApellido();
        String rt = cl.getRut();
        int nc = c.getNumerocta();
        response.sendRedirect("Saldo.jsp?sl="+sl+"&nom="+nom+"&ap="+ap+"&rt="+rt+"&nc="+nc);
        misession.setAttribute(rut, cl);
        PrintWriter pw= response.getWriter();
        pw.println("<html><body>Producto en session</body></html>");
```

pero no puedo recuperarlo despues

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
       String rt = request.getParameter("rt");
      HttpSession misession= request.getSession();
        Cliente cl= (Cliente) misession.getAttribute("rt");
      int co = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("co"));
      int cd = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("cd"));
      int mo = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("mo"));
      String clave = request.getParameter("pw");
      Cuenta cu = cuentaController.buscarCuenta(co);
      String nom = cl.getNombre();
      String ap = cl.getApellido();
      int nc=co;
```

Comment: Pon la traza del error. Y ¿qué es lo que no recuperas? ¿La sesión o el atributo?

Comment: el atributo cl.getnombre(); me tira null, creo por que el el cliente esta null

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at servlets.transferencia.processRequest(transferencia.java:52)
 at servlets.transferencia.doGet(transferencia.java:80)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)

Comment: Supongo le línea 52 es `String nom = cl.getNombre();`. Prueba con lo que te he puesto en la respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder poner el código te pongo una respuesta pero esto debería ser comentario.

Creo que el fallo lo tienes porque en sesión guardas:

```
misession.setAttribute(rut, cl);
```

pero recuperas:

```
misession.getAttribute("rt");
```

Según lo veo debería ser así:

```
Cliente cl= (Cliente) misession.getAttribute(rt);
```

donde `rt` es el parámetro que has recuperado del `request`.

Prueba y ya nos contarás.

Comment: me funciono, muchas gracias, ahora si me puedes poner como cerrar session te lo agradeceria mucho

Comment: `misession.close();` debe valer. Pero cierra sesión cuando ya has terminado de hacer todo, es decir al salir de la aplicación. No lo hagas en el servlet cuando has terminado de recuperar las cosas que necesitas

Comment: Por favor, no publiques una respuesta diciendo "gracias". En su lugar, **[acepta la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** que consideres como la mejor solución a tu problema. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/165731)